# How can I configure which devices are able to use my app? (ie ALL devices, including older gen)

Tags: iphone, ios4, app-store, compatibility

I have set minimum iOS version to 3.1.3, added a required device architecture of either armv6 or armv7 and it still will not allow iPod touches before third generation to install the app. Am I missing a setting/plist entry somewhere that allows me to easily adjust which devices are supported?

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the iOS deployment target (to 3.1.3 in your case) doesn't necessarily mean that your app will be able to run on that version. It also depends on what APIs you use. As a concrete example, if you were to use `NSArray`'s `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` somewhere in your app, it would only run on iOS 4.0 and later as previous versions don't include that method.

You should set the iOS deployment target to the oldest version *that you've successfully tested*. While you could just read the API diffs that Apple provides, you might miss something and that would be bad.